# Is there any benefit to add doOnSuccess( ) inside of mono.compose( ) vs simple mono.doOnSuccess( )

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-boot-actuator

Looked into the Spring Actuator [MetricsWebFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5c04531681b8fd63d86a40039900cb168629e852/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/reactive/server/MetricsWebFilter.java#L58)

And saw this code:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange).compose((call) -> filter(exchange, call));
}

private Publisher<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, Mono<Void> call) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    return call.doOnSuccess((done) -> success(exchange, start))
    ... more code ...
}
```

Would be there any difference without the `compose()` mapping?

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange).doOnSuccess( ... ) ... more code...
}
```

My clues were that `compose()` is executed once per each subscriber compared to `transform()`. `doOnSuccess()` however is also executed once per subscriber.

Is it just for convenience, to use a `filter(...)` function instead of the inline code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has several small benefits in terms of readability:

- the code is better encapsulated in the filter method
- the invocation is more readable (reads as transformations occurs). compare to calling the method classically: `return filter(exchange, chain.filter(exchange))`.

But in my opinion the more important bit is that `compose` is `Subscriber`-specific. As a consequence, the `filter(exchange, call)` will be invoked on every subscription.
**And thus the timing code at the beginning will be relevant** ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a convenience, as the filter method is a bit longer that your code snippet suggests, and there are both `doOnSuccess` and `doOnError` operators.